# How do I get ReadLineAsSecureString() to accept pipe input?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

When I am using `cmd` and pipe to a `powershell` which uses `ReadLine()` to read input, it accepts the pipe input as expected:

```
C:\Users\ohnob>ECHO hi|powershell -Command "write-host $host.UI.ReadLine()"
hi
hi
```

However, when am using `cmd` and pipe to `powershell` using `ReadLineAsSecureString()`, it hangs until I type return into the terminal:

```
C:\Users\ohnob>ECHO hi|powershell -Command "write-host $host.UI.ReadLineAsSecureString()"
```

I need to read as a secure string (using asterisks) when the session is interactive. But I need to read pipe input when there is pipe input. How do I accomplish this in `powershell`? I expect I could be able to detect whether or not stdin is a pipe somehow and then conditionally use `ReadLine()` instead of `ReadLineAsSexcureString()`, but I don’t know how to get a handle of standard input in powershell—I only get access to this [`PSHostUserInterface`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.host.pshostuserinterface?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0) object.

EDIT: To clarify, when I use `ReadLineAsSecureString()` or `ReadLine()`, I expect it to read **one line** from input. That allows it to be used multiple times and the user to provide multiple values to the script. I expect any answers to be drop-in replacements for the functions I use except without the issues that I am trying to avoid. Thanks!

Comment: That's kinda sorta deliberate. Piping unencrypted input isn't secure, which is why `ReadLineAsSecureString` wants to you to type, character by character. So you'll need to fundamentally distinguish between these modes anyway. I suggest something like `"if ($input.MoveNext()) { ConvertTo-SecureString $input.Current -AsPlainText -Force } else { Read-Host -AsSecureString }"` (disclaimer: not well tested, and it'll ignore multiple lines on input in any case).

Comment: @JeroenMostert May you give a reference for why piping input is considered insecure? I know that `ECHO` is an internal `cmd` command, so it shouldn’t even show up in Task Manager with its Command Line visible. The data in pipes between processes would normally not be readable without a debugger.

Comment: Yes, but the whole point of `SecureString` is to give you (some) security even if access to memory is present, as the value is encrypted by default (except for the brief times it's not). Any instance where the string is ever present unencrypted in memory (like the output buffers of `cmd`) defeats its protection. (This is also why `SecureString` is a pretty niche product, and why PowerShell focuses on, at *worst*, reading and writing it in encrypted form from files.)

Comment: See also "[How secure is `SecureString`?](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=netframework-4.7.2#how-secure-is-securestring)". Spoilers: in most cases, actually not very, even if the designers tried to discourage the insecure cases as much as possible, because even the OS has no native support for them.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I understand the point of `SecureString`, but I am not desiring that behavior. I am only using the `ReadLineAsSecureString()` so that the `cmd` prints out asterisks instead of showing the input that the user typed on the screen. I’m worried about screenpeaking here—not someone pulling out my SSD while my computer is running and examining the swap file.

Comment: In that case, you should be perfectly fine with detecting piped input with `$input`, and using `Read-Host -AsSecureString` for the other case, regardless of what you then proceed to do with the `SecureString`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yeah, that’s the approach I’m planning to use. But it’d be much nicer if there were a way to make `powershell` just behave like normal so that I only need to write one command for this common use case instead of rewriting again the `if ([System.Console]::IsInputRedirected)` and both `ReadLine` and `ReadLineAsSecureString()` all the time.

Comment: You could always open an [issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues)... But I'm afraid that, with the paranoia PowerShell has for `SecureString`, this *is* "behaving like normal". Deceptive naming aside, `ReadLineAsSecureString` is not a simple counterpart to `ReadLine`.

Comment: Why are you piping into `powershell.exe` from cmd instead of just using a powershell script?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Because nobody maintaining the CMD script knows powershell and, if we were to switch to something like powershell, it might just as well be csharp instead of powershell.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 In this precise case, I have am launching my script from an interactive `CMD` prompt. Normally, things which ask optional questions can be silenced by just appending `<NUL`. I am trying to make this powershell thing written by someone else compatible with my personal convention for forcing the script to run non-interactively.

Comment: Seems like it'd be significantly less effort just to learn powershell, honestly.  It's the way Windows administration is going.  There's a fairly large step between powershell and C# (until you get into advanced usage).

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Does it make a difference that I’m not writing a script which administers Windows?

Comment: It makes me seriously question what you're doing with `cmd` that interacts with non-Windows

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I never said non-Windows. Just not Windows administration… But your issue seems unrelated to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jeroen Mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert) makes some good points in the comments, notably that `$host.UI.ReadLineAsSecureString()` / `Read-Host -AsSecureString` *presumably* *by design* do not accept pipeline input, for security reasons<sup>[1]</sup>.

Therefore, you must explicitly distinguish between receiving pipeline input and not receiving any:

- PowerShell provides access to stdin input piped from the outside via the automatic `$Input` variable.
- `$MyInvocation.ExpectingInput` generally indicates if pipeline input is present.

If there is pipeline input, pass its *first line*<sup>[2]</sup> to `ConvertTo-SecureString`;
if there isn't, call `Read-Host -AsSecureString`:

```
$secStr = if ($MyInvocation.ExpectingInput) {
    # Alternatively, use $firstLine = [console]::ReadLine() - thanks, @binki
    $firstLine = $($null = $Input.MoveNext(); $Input.Current)
    ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force $firstLine
  } else {
    Read-Host -AsSecureString -Prompt 'Enter secret'
  }
```

As a command line to call from `cmd.exe` that also outputs the result:

```
C:>echo hi| powershell -Command "$secStr = if ($MyInvocation.ExpectingInput) { $firstLine = $($null = $Input.MoveNext(); $Input.Current); ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force $firstLine } else { Read-Host -AsSecureString -Prompt 'Enter secret' }l$secStr"
```

Note, however, that secure strings by design print generically as `System.Security.SecureString`, so that's all you'll see.

---

<sup>[1] I'm *speculating* in the absence of documentation on that aspect. *Piping* a plain-text string to `Read-Host -AsSecureString` definitely has a *greater potential* of being insecure: the plain-text string being piped may be persisted that way somewhere and, at least hypothetically, if you use something like `MyCustomEcho.exe secret | ...`, the process' command line will reflect the secret information.

Either way, passing plain text to `ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText` is always an option, where the *additional* need to pass `-Force` also indicates that PowerShell considers using plain-text input that wasn't typed interactively.</sup>

<sup>[2] The automatic `$Input` variable is an *enumerator* (type ) that enumerates lines from stdin *on demand*. *Indexed* access such as `$Input[0]` is *not* supported; instead, you must use `.MoveFirst()` to start the enumeration and then access the `.Current` property to get the first line. That way, the remaining elements aren't consumed and later use of `$Input` yields the remaining lines.

The only reason for the `$(...)` around `$null = $Input.MoveNext(); $Input.Current`  is so that the two statements can be wrapped in a *single* statement that returns the first line, for conceptual clarity; using `$null = $Input.MoveNext()` first and `$firstLine = $Input.Current` is perfectly fine also.</sup>

Comment: @binki: Re security: you're right - the claim was speculative (I've made that clear int the answer), but see the footnote that I just added.

Comment: I appreciate it, @binki. Your `[Console]::ReadLine()` solution is a perfectly valid alternative (I've added it to the answer in a comment), and arguably more readable. My preference was for use of `$Input` because it works consistently across multiple scenarios, but, as you can see, extracting the 1st input object (line) in isolation is somewhat awkward, though my use of `$(...)` may have obscured things further - see footnote [2].